# Over-success when holding in Diplomacy

Tags: diplomacy

What happens if an army is holding and has more support than an army attacking     it?  It didn't say in the copy of the rules on Wikipedia.

Comment: What outcomes are you trying to decide between?  I don't see where there is any ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Units can move to another area. If the area is occupied, it is seen as an attack. And that needs to be resolved.

Each unit (either moving or held) has a value of 1. And each unit that successfully supports a unit, adds 1 to the total value. And the total values are compared.

There are now three possibilities:

- The attacking unit has a higher value. The attack wins and the defending unit must retreat (or is disbanded).
- The attacking unit has the same value as the defender. The attack fails. Both units stay at their own area.
- The defending unit has a higher value. The attack fails. Both units stay at their own area. (There is no additional advantage to the defender because of the higher value).

Comment: To be precise, your statement should read (my **emphasis**) "*So if the defender has greater **or equal** power, the attack fails*".

Comment: I reworded the answer. Hopefully it is more clear now. The central point is that there is no added advantage because of the overwhelming defence.

Answer (score 4):

A unit holding that has **more** *or equal* *valid* support **to hold** than its attacker stays put (wins).  Here are some examples:

## Example 0: Greater Valid Support To Hold

- Army Gascony -> Paris
- Army Brest supports Gascony -> Paris
- Army Paris Holds
- Army Belgium supports Paris
- Army Ruhr supports Pairs

Paris's support plus itself is 3 strong, and Gascony's support plus itself is 2 strong, so the defense is greater and Paris holds

## Example 1: Equal Valid Support To Hold

- Army Gascony -> Paris
- Army Brest supports Gascony -> Paris
- Army Paris Holds
- Army Belgium supports Paris

Paris's support plus itself is 2 strong, and Gascony's support plus itself is 2 strong and the tie does to the defender so Paris holds

## Example 2: An invalid support

- Army Gascony -> Paris
- Army Brest supports Gascony -> Paris
- Army Paris Holds
- Fleet Belgium supports Paris (* invalid -- you can only support where you can move *)

Paris's support from Belgium was invalid, so it doesn't exist.  Paris is at one strong, and Gascony's support plus itself is 2 strong and so Gascony wins and Paris is dislodged.

## Example 3: A support of a move instead of a hold

- Army Gascony -> Paris
- Army Brest supports Gascony -> Paris
- Army Paris Holds
- Army Belgium supports Paris -> Brest (* invalid -- Paris isn't trying to move to Brest *)

Paris's support from Belgium wasn't to hold, so it doesn't help.  Paris is at one strong, and Gascony's support plus itself is 2 strong and so Gascony wins and Paris is dislodged.